# Convert single `char` to `byte[]`, encoding aware

Tags: java, character-encoding

With a `String` one can call `s.getBytes(charset);`, what's the equivalent for a single `char`?   For example, i want the UTF8 encoding for the "`♥`" symbol:

```
byte[] x = getBytesForChar('♥', StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       // x should now be {0xE2, 0x99, 0xA5}
```

What real method replaces `getBytesForChar` ?

Of course i can convert the `char` to a `String`, and call `getBytes` on that instead, but it seems like an unnecessary overhead.  I've had a quick poke around in the guts of `String`, but most of the encoding methods disappear down into package scope internal classes

Comment: What's wrong with `byte[] x = String.valueOf('♥').getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`?  I don't see overhead there.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch it seems like allocating a `char[]` with one element, then constructing a `String` from it, only to pass that to a method that presumably breaks it back down into `char`s to do the actual encoding is unnecessary

Comment: @Stik Unfortunately I don't think there is an equivalent method. I agree that using the String class seems like overkill, and having to use it for a single character just feels wrong. It would be nice if the `Character` class had a static `getBytes()` method: `byte[] x = Character.getBytes('♥', StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`. The only obvious alternative to using `String.getBytes()` is to write your own `getBytesForChar()`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is a reason to use `String` to convert a character to `byte[]`. When you try to convert single `char` to `byte[]`, there is a problem: Shift Out / Shift In. The representation of a character will vary by the position that the character appears in a string.

For example, a single Japanese character 'あ' is represented as `0x44 0x81` in CP930 (a kind of EBCDIC). When you insert it in a string, you need to append a Shift Out (`0x0e`) at the start of a sequence of multi-byte characters and Shift In (`0x0f`) at the end of the sequence.

So a string that contains single Japanese character 'あ' will be `0x0e 0x44 0x81 0x0f` in CP930. In a similar way, 'ああ' will be `0x0e 0x44 0x81 0x44 0x81 0x0f`. In this situation, you cannot insert `0x0e 0x44 0x81 0x0f` into the center of `0x0e 0x44 0x81 0x44 0x81 0x0f` to get the representation of 'あああ'. You have to give consideration to the needs for Shift Out / Shift In according to the position of the characters.

So when you try to convert a character into a byte array, you have to show the position of the character and the other characters around it -- it means the sequence of characters: String.